Blob Trigger Azure Function is not triggering automatically for every file upload in the specified Azure Storage container
I have create Azure Function with Blob trigger on storage account but when I upload blob in storage account function is not triggering.
I have created environment variable with ConenctionString with my storage account connection string.
Plan Type: App Service plan
SKU and size: Premium0V3 P0v3
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="container/directory",
                               connection="ConnectionString") 
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

Can you please help to share solution?
I have created environment variable with ConenctionString with my storage account connection string.

How many blobs do you have in that container? The basic blob trigger becomes unreliable after like 1000 blobs..

Naimesh Vaja, Check if below solution works for you?

Initially I am also getting same issue but after adding the storage account connection string in environment variables in portal worked successfully like below.
I have created Blob trigger function with runtime stack python.
Check the below code worked successfully.
Function code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="outcontainer",
                            connection="rithwikstore_STORAGE") 
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "your-storage conn-string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "rithwikstore_STORAGE": "your-storage conn-string"
  }
}


Ensure that the connection string of storage account can be added in function app  App settings like below:

When i run the above code i have uploaded the blobs in storage container then it got triggered function successfully. check below:

I have deployed the function into premium plan of function app in the portal.


The function worked in azure portal as well. check below:
Output:

